# Installing Python modules Tkinter, wx (Windows 8)

Tags: python, windows, module, tkinter, wxwidgets

I'm trying to install Python modules on my PC. I don't know where to get Tkinter, wx and how to install them.
Can you, please, help me?

Comment: http://www.wxpython.org/download.php

Comment: tkinter is included in python. No need to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is a part of Python, at least on Windows. I had to install it on my Mac. Anyway, here are a few links:

- https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html

wxPython is a separate GUI library and it **not** a part of the Python standard library. It can be found here for Windows:

- http://wxpython.org/download.php#msw

Note: You cannot create an application that uses both Tkinter and wxPython at the same time (unless you're doing something really crazy with threads/processes).